# Trigger tag inside a block with a different tag

Tags: ansible

If I have a playbook like this

```
   tasks:
     block:
     - ....
       tags: tasktag
     tags: blocktag
```

Can I trigger the task tag without including the block tag or does the block tag need to be mentioned for the task tag to be specified (and only to run that task)

So, I want to know if I can run `ansible-playbook -t tasktag file.yml` to trigger only that task in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can execute just a tag within a `block`. For example

file.yml

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: Task#1

  - block:
    - debug:
        msg: Block - Task#1

    - debug:
        msg: Block - Task#1 - tasktag
      tags: tasktag

    tags: blocktag

  - debug:
      msg: Task#2
```

Execute

```
ansible-playbook -t tasktag file.yml
```

It returns

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Block - Task#1 - tasktag"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```